# Single Line Binary Decoder

Tags: arduino, digital-logic, wiring

How would I implement a single line binary decoder.
Table:

```
Input  Output1  Output2
0       1        0
1       0        1
```

It also looks as if a flip flop would work with this. I would be using this with a micro controller as an input.

Comment: ... out1=not(IN), out2=IN. Really you should not have any difficulty designing it on a micro or with discrete logic.

Comment: external not gate? transistor inverter? There are many ways to do it.

Comment: Use a logical not discrete logic IC to create both outputs then.

Comment: A not gate. Nothing more. Output2 = Input. Output 1 = !Input.

Comment: So trivial. Write a logic function for each one of the outputs.

Comment: A single NOT gate will work just fine. LOOK AT TOM CARPENTER'S ANSWER! He literally handed it to you!

Comment: @Goodwin, A flip flop will do nothing if you don't provide a clock signal. Since your problem says nothing about there being a clock signal available, or wanting to syncronize the outputs with a clock signal, there is no reason to think a flip flop or latch will help solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I feel like just giving up.

[image: Not gate.]

Then I think maybe I should just **not** and miraculously my state is inverted.

Comment: Patent this idea now!

Answer (score 0):

This is padding................

[image]